# Contact form - HTML/PHP - Cannot post

Tags: php, html

I am experiencing some issues when trying to make a contact form work the way I want it to on a website I'm working on.

When I click the "send" button a new page appears with the text "Cannot post /contact_form.php". Why does this occur?

In my eyes the code seems correct.

Update, here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="email">Your email:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="message">Your message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
</div>
<input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" /></form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php $action=$_REQUEST['action'];if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
{
?>
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your name:<br>
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your email:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your message:<br>
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
</form>
<?php
} else                /* send the submitted data */
{
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
    {
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
    }
else{       
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
    mail("my_mail@mail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
    echo "Email sent!";
    }
}  ?>
```

Comment: Could be for any number of reasons but without seeing your code it is very hard to offer a proper explanation / solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code. the point is in the sentence: "In my eyes" so share what you are looking at

Comment: Problem resolved. Created a local server via XAMPP and downloaded a test mail server via toolheap.